# Flow finish behavior - flow called by custom URL button

Tags: visual-flows

I have a Visual Flow that is triggered by a Button on a record.  The flow sends an email notification and posts to chatter (without requiring any user input).  When the flow is finished I just want the user to end up back on the same record they started from, but using retURL is giving me some extra page reloads [image: screenshot]

the button URL is

```
/flow/Send_email_notification_to_merchandiser?MerchWorkOrderID={!Merchandiser_Work_Order__c.Id}&retURL=/lightning/r/Merchandiser_Work_Order__c/{!Merchandiser_Work_Order__c.Id}/view
```

and the syntax of the retURL is

```
/lightning/r/Merchandiser_Work_Order__c/{!Merchandiser_Work_Order__c.Id}/view
```

Ultimately, the user does end up on the correct Record page, but I'm hoping to avoid all of the "screen flashes".  Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to you Id of your record. See below

```
/flow/Send_email_notification_to_merchandiser?MerchWorkOrderID={!Merchandiser_Work_Order__c.Id}&retURL={!Merchandiser_Work_Order__c.Id}
```